# Issue with contact import Street Address -- drops address if over 25 chars in length

Tags: contacts, data-import

I am working on a test system as we work through the process to import data from BasicFunder into CiviCRM.  I've hit a strange issue with import of Contact address data.  A number of imported records are showing FALSE as the Street Address.  Some investigation reveals that if an address in the CSV file that is mapped to Street Address is over 25 characters in length it is not imported and the field is left as FALSE.  I thought I saw a post somewhere that indicated this field is 96 chars in length.  Anyone have any ideas?  This is just a test system so easily enough rebuilt if there is a fundamental flaw in it somewhere.

Comment: What version of CiviCRM are you using?  Can you reproduce it on https://dmaster.demo.civicrm.org (don't upload any real data!)?

Comment: Hi, Aidan:  5.3.3.2 on Wordpress.  Weirdly it worked on an earlier incarnation of the test platform.  Also, I can modify record after import and it takes the change.  Not sure how I would test this on dmaster without loading real data.

Comment: Just tried importing my record (which messes up on my test bench) into the dmaster and it worked fine.  Sigh.

Comment: So, I did some more testing.  Deleted my record out of my test system.  Used the same CSV file as I used to upload to dmaster and retried the import, same results.  Upgraded my test system to 5.35.0, deleted my record and reimported, same results.  Now banging my head against the wall.

Comment: Have you got some extensions doing strange things?  Might be worth disabling all extensions on your test system and trying again.

Comment: No weird extensions.  Did a full net new rebuild for test system and now works.  Very odd.

Comment: maybe add an Answer to your own question then just to close this off